# How do I require only one of a set of properties are specified with json schema

Tags: jsonschema

I have three properties: one, two, three.

If one of those properties is specified the other two must not be included. So this is a mutual exclusion rule.

I tried to write this rule in a concise way, but this appears not to work:

```
"oneOf": [
    {
        "required": ["one"],
        "not": {"required": ["two", "three"]}
    },
    {
        "required": ["two"],
        "not": {"required": ["one", "three"]}
    },
    {
        "required": ["three"],
        "not": {"required": ["one", "two"]}
    },
]
```

That will only throw an error if all three are specified together instead of just more than one. I almost want something like an enum, but for properties- to be able to say only one of this list of properties can be specified.

## EDIT

Per user comments I removed the `not`s and that worked, but I'm really disappointed in the error message:

```
- (root): Must validate one and only one schema (oneOf)
- myObj.0: Must validate one and only one schema (oneOf)
```

Super not helpful. It doesn't say anything about which properties are failing validation. Is there a way to describe this in a way where users will get an error that looks more like:

```
- myObj.0: Must include one and only one of properties one, two, or three
```

Otherwise it kind of leaves you in the dark and forces you to review the actual schema instead of making it more obvious.

Comment: Just remove the `not`s. `oneOf` is already a mutually exclusive constraint. You don't need to do that part manually. If I have time later I'll answer the question with an explanation about why your `not`s don't work the way you think they do.

Comment: I should have know! But please look at my edit. While that works as it should the error message is a bummer. Is there a way to describe this rule that gives my users better info?

Comment: Error messaging is going to be specific to the implementation. This is the best way to express this constraint in a schema. There's nothing you can change in the schema to make the messaging better. The best you can do is request that the implementation improve their messaging.

Comment: There is now a standard error message format defined in the specification -- you could request that the implementation follow that format. it includes both the location in the data and the location in the schema where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxProperties: 1` along with `additionalProperties: false`.

`additionalProperties: false` prevents the inclusion of properties you don't define, which means they *have* to use yours, but then `maxProperties: 1` will require that they can only use one of them.